# PSQL -f Parameter Hanging on Windows 8.1

Tags: postgresql, git-bash

I've been using PSQL 14 on my Windows 10 desktop with Git Bash for a while now without issue.  Recently I've had to transition to a Windows 8.1 laptop, and I've come across a problem with running the `filename` parameter for PSQL.  When attempting to run a SQL file with the line `psql.exe -U <user> -f src/sql/test.sql` the terminal hangs until I use Ctrl+C to exit the command.  I can run `psql -U <user>` and then copy & paste the SQL file text into the terminal to get the results I want, but I don't get why this issue is happening in the first place.

I've checked my PATH environment variables and I do have both the /bin and /lib paths in there.  I have also tested changing -f with the < operator, which didn't change anything.  Running PSQL on Windows 8.1 isn't an issue, it's just this particular command.

Comment: Does it work if you use `cmd.exe` instead of this "git bash" thing? Does `\i test.sql` from within `psql` work?

Comment: Cmd.exe works!  That determined that something's wrong with Git Bash, and I'd like to find out what, but for now I'll use cmd.exe for psql.